# Using scala.sys.process in playframework 2

Tags: scala, powershell, playframework-2.0

I am trying allow access of some local system services to other users via the web.

After some googleing, I ended up choosing to use the Play framework to act as the front end to accept the webservice calls. Upon receiving the call, Play will execute some command via powershell. E.g.,

In my Application.scala

```
def test = Action {
    println(Seq("powershell.exe", "dir", "c:").!)
    Ok("")
}
```

The corresponding route info is

```
GET      /test     controllers.Application.test
```

My problem is that although the result of the call to powershell gets printed out, the method never returns. From the client (browser) perspective, it just continuously wait for the call to .../test to come back.

I have test the code itself and it ran fine. My problem seems to occur only when I run it through Play.

Any advice is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

From `ProcessBuilder` scaladoc:

```
abstract def !(log: ProcessLogger): Int
    Starts the process represented by this builder, blocks until it exits, 
    and returns the exit code.
```

Try use `lines` instead - it will return a `Stream`

**EDIT**

If a command has completed already, haven't you already read its output from the stream? After that, just call `Process.destroy()` from different stream, manually. Create an actor and send him a message from thread that parses `Stream`, it should close process. Or use `CountDownLatch` fow awaiting, its a more Java way.

Comment: I tried "run". Although it returns right away, the same problem occurs when I start reading the stream. It will print out the output of the system command (e.g., dir c:) and then somehow hold up the whole thread even though the command has completed already.